# about Build.VERSION.SDK_INT

Tags: java, android, compilation

From the android.jar source code, the SDK_INT is a constants:

```
public static final int SDK_INT = 0;
```

So, it is my understanding, when compiling the code, the java compile will remove below code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
     //Some logic for device above 11.
}
```

From the test/debug result, the Build.VERSION.SDK_INT is not zero, it seems I missing something about android compiling.

Comment: From the source `public static final int SDK_INT = SystemProperties.getInt(
                "ro.build.version.sdk", 0);` . So default value is 0 only .

Comment: `SystemProperties` is the responsible for About System details .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy from ADM's comments:

From the source public static final int SDK_INT = SystemProperties.getInt( "ro.build.version.sdk", 0);